# Google chat Presence/Status API

Tags: google-chat

Is there apis for the user status https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9093489?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop ?

What i would like to do:

- update my presence via a script that i have on my pc.
- get to know the presence of other my coworkers to automatically send a reminder (or not) when there's action triggered by this script on my pc

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [Google Chat API](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest) doesn't seem to have the features that you're currently looking for, and I think that it's similar to the request [API to modify user settings - Specifically Status for Vacationing etc.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/209825728)

The summary of that is for Google to provide an API to configure chat status and read chat status information. It's requesting to create an API that allows developers to write code that can programmatically update users Chat Status, such as  Vacationing / On holidays etc. which I believe answers update my presence via a script that i have on my pc.

It also talks about how It would be great to be able to read this Chat status info from an API too, to enable creation of dashboards showing who's working/away right now and make it easier to have unplanned meetings based on who's around. which I suppose relates to get to know the presence of other my coworkers to automatically send a reminder (or not) when there's action triggered by this script on my pc.

Now, if this is similar to what you'd like to do in general, feel free to click on the +1 located in the upper right of the page, as that tells Google that you're also requesting for the feature to be implemented. If not, you can always submit a new [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).

Comment: gr8, thanks. that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer